# Why would the SPD prefer a coalition where they are the junior partner to one where they are the largest party?

Tags: germany, coalition, berlin

In the [2023 Berlin elections](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wahl_zum_Abgeordnetenhaus_von_Berlin), the result for the largest parties was:

| Party | Seats |
| --- | --- |
| CDU | 52 |
| SPD | 34 |
| Greens | 34 |
| Left | 22 |

(the SPD received 53 votes more than the Greens)

80 seats are needed for a majority, so this allows for majority coalitions:

| Coalition | Seats | Mayor |
| --- | --- | --- |
| CDU, SPD | 86 | CDU |
| SPD, Greens, Left | 90 | SPD |
| CDU, Greens | 86 | CDU |

The Berlin news reports that the leader of the SPD is [recommending her party to start coalition talks with the CDU](https://www.rbb24.de/politik/wahl/abgeordnetenhaus/agh-2023/beitraege/berlin-regierung-giffey-vorschlag-koalition-cdu-spd-wegner.html).  Such a coalition would mean that the SPD loses the position of mayor.  In a coalition with Greens and Left (which is also the previous coalition), the SPD would retain the position of mayor.  It would seem that it should be strongly preferable for the SPD to hold the position of mayor than to not hold the position of mayor.

Why would the SPD prefer a coalition where they lose the position of mayor to one where they can retain it?

Comment: The coalition where the Left are present seems to be problematic in curent situation.

Comment: Without knowing the details, two generic reasons: It is easier to deal with one partner than with two, or the demands (either in positions or in political actions) by Left or Greens are too burdersome for the SPD electorate.

Comment: I would suggest waiting until the end of Wednesday to see whether this actually happens. The FAZ (a conservative newspaper covering all of Germany) claims Ms Giffey will announce this publically on Wednesday and even threatened to resign if this is not done. The other sources, like rbb24 all just write some version of 'there are rumors'.

Comment: @quarague True, maybe they're all deliberate rumours that aim to make the green party demand less.

Comment: The SPD may simply agree on more things with the CDU.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After waiting for 24 hours, a few more details are now available. The *Landesvorstand* (state committee) of the SPD has now [voted for](https://tagesspiegel.liveblog.pro/lb-tagesspiegel/blogs/63e53d33d0b38875c20227a8/index.html?liveblog._id=urn:newsml:localhost:2023-03-01T20:37:09.458358:6a908cab-b9dc-4663-a897-8bcd19845859__editorial) taking up coalition talks with the CDU, and the *Sondierungspapier* (exploratory results paper) has been [quoted in the media](https://www.tagesspiegel.de/berlin/sondierungspapier-cdu-und-spd-in-berlin-einigen-sich-auf-rahmengesetz-fur-enteignungen-9437063.html).

Two quotes make statements about why the current coalition of SPD, Greens and Left is appraised to be no longer a "durable and robust project" (*dauerhaftes und belastbares Projekt*):

> Als Gründe führen die Sozialdemokraten „stark überwiegende Eigeninteressen der Grünen“ an. Diese hätten auch Ziele des bisherigen Koalitionsvertrages relativieren wollen...
>
> Ebenfalls als Hinderungsgrund wird die „stark angespannte parteiinterne Situation bei der Linken“ angeführt. Die Sondierer schreiben: „Auf Landesebene bestehen erhebliche Zweifel an der Durchsetzungsfähigkeit verabredeter Positionen in der Breite der Partei.“

(Translation by [DeepL](https://www.deepl.com/de/translator))

> As reasons, the Social Democrats cite "strongly predominant self-interests of the Greens". The Greens would also have wanted to relativize the goals of the previous coalition agreement...
>
> The "very tense internal situation within the Left Party" is also cited as an obstacle. The explorers write: "At the state level, there are considerable doubts about the ability to implement agreed positions across the party."

I'll follow up with some speculations of my own about what you can read between the lines.

First, the SPD is divided between a left and a right wing. Mayor [Franziska Giffey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Franziska_Giffey) and parliamentary speaker [Raed Saleh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raed_Saleh) belong to the right wing, and currently hold a majority in the state party committee. But the left voices are strong. During the day, a number of them could be heard that strongly oppose a coalition with the CDU, among them the youth organisation Jusos, and (regionally) prominent party members like [Mark Rackles](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mark_Rackles), [Sawsan Chebly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sawsan_Chebli) or [Annika Klose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Annika_Klose). At the last election for party chairwomanship, Giffey could only win 60% of the votes. ([Here](https://frank-stauss.de/index.php/die-selbstpulverisierung-der-spd-berlin/) is a longer piece by a former SPD election campaigner outlining the left wing position.)

Continuing the SPD/Greens/Left coalition would mean to further strengthen the left wing agenda inside the party, with an inherent risk that when the candidates for the next state elections are selected, Giffey and Saleh will no longer be able to win the leader positions.

Second, the potshot at the internal situation of the Left reminds of the traditional problem the SPD has with this party: From their perspective, the Left is just another social democratic party that competes for the same voters. Strategically, the SPD dreams of removing them from the political landscape and returning to the comfortable situation of times gone by when they were the only credible left party in German parliaments.

Currently the federal Left party is divided and was barely able to retain its presence in the Bundestag. The Berlin state organisation is one of the few that are more or less undivided and has a track record of opposing both old-time GDR sympathisers and [Querfront](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_Position) proponents like Sarah Wagenknecht. Their senators (government members) are visible and relatively popular.

Sending them to the opposition benches might look like a possible divide-and-conquer move from the viewpoint of the SPD.

Answer (score 2):

If the CDU and Greens joined up they would be in the majority and the SPD would be left out. They have to weigh the risk of the CDU/Greens joining up instead of the Greens/Left being willing to join them. While SPD/Greens/Left would be better for the SPD it might be argued that CDU/Greens would be better for the greens as either way they won't be first and there is one less party to deal with in the majority.

Comment: A CDU/Greens coalition was never a realistic prospect. It was a tactical move by the Greens to enter talks, but the political differences are too great for any compromise to ever gain majority support inside the Green party. Such a coalition was never more than a pipe dream by conservative political commentators.

Comment: @ccprog That is good to know.

Comment: @ccprog: it would be helpful if you added answer that explains why, especially at the local/regional level.

Comment: @Fizz While I can talk about CDU/Greens, this would fall short of answering the question, i. e. explaining the CDU/SPD option. Especially after the Giffey comment about the ["workable way"](https://taz.de/Regierungsbildung-in-Berlin/!5919156/) regarding the expropriation referendum, I still are as suprised as gerrit was. Answers will probably emerge in the next few days.

Comment: I have a hard time understanding why the Greens would prefer CDU over SPD+Linke.  Tactically, sure, but what could the CDU give them that SPD+Linke won't be willing to give them?

Comment: @ccprog This is true for Berlin but CDU/Green coalitions exist on work fine in some other German states. During the election campaign in Berlin both the CDU and the Greens made public statements that essentially said they don't want to work together. Both were a lot more open about working together with the SPD (and the Linke in case of the Greens).

Comment: @gerrit your negotiating power is precisely equal to your willingness to walk away. The possibility of CDU/Greens gives Greens more negotiating power with SPD/Linke. But it works both ways: the possibility of CDU/SPD gives SPD more negotiating power with Greens/Linke.

Comment: @user253751 Well, only if the SPD believe the Greens are seriously considering a coalition with the CDU and that this is not just show for negotiations.

Comment: @gerrit One less party to share power with? There is an advantage to being in a two party coalition over a three party one. And as you are asking about why the SPD made the choice instead of the Greens it should be remembered that the SPD has to worry about them being in power or another coalition forming and them not being in power.

Comment: @gerrit On the flip side the SPD needs to get both the Greens and Left to agree if they want to get power that way.

Comment: @JoeW The Left doesn't have any other options to govern & the Greens don't have any sensible options. Both were always going to agree to a coalition with the SPD. It's just that apparently the SPD thinks that it has more in common with the (extremely) right-wing CDU in Berlin (which might actually be true, at least for the right wing of the SPD that is currently holding the reins of power in the party).

Comment: @tim I understand that the Left doesn't have any other options which is why I didn't talk about them making a choice. The choices I gave was the Greens having a choice between a coalition of two or three parties and how they could want one with fewer parties to allow for them to have more say. Because of this the SPD needs to weigh the options of how to form a coalition and the risks if the CPU and Greens join up leaving the SPD out of the equation.

Comment: @JoeW You said they need "to get both the Greens and Left to agree". But the 2 vs 3 math is also a bit wonky. The Greens have much more in common with the Linke and more with the SPD than with the CDU. Many of their wants overlap and they would automatically get them. "more say" doesn't mean anything if they still gain less of what they want. There was no real risk of a CDU/Grüne coalition, the reasons for the decision of the SPD are elsewhere.

Comment: @tim While that might be true there is still the possibility of a deal being struck that leaves the SPD out of control of power.